# Launching a program so that it opens in center of the launching application

Tags: macos, process

Launching a program so that it opens in center of the launching application.

Platform: Mac
Launching mechanism: a c++ program launches using system()

Currently I observe the program launched pushes it to left most part of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

> Launching a program so that it opens in center of the launching application.

On Mac OS X systems, programs don't launch into a specific area of the screen. When they launch, they become the "front" application, and take over the menubar area with their own menus. They may choose to open a window after they have opened, or not.

Find out if the program in question accepts apple events / applescript commands. If so, you may be able to ask the program to position a window in a particular location.

Also, if you still have to use `system`, you can send apple events with the `osascript` command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `system`, there's really nothing you can do, since you've implicitly delegated everything about the process except its startup args to the OS. There may be ways to accomplish this using other OSX-specific APIs, but not with the parameters you've outlined here.